# Rails goto another page in particular section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have `<div id="all-comments">Comments</div>`
section on my Posts show page. I have a link on my Posts index page which shows Number of comments and when clicked on comments i want to go to `example.com/posts/1#all-comments`.
Now i am using `<%= link_to post_path(@post) %>` - This generates `example.com/posts/1` but i want #all-comments at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered (albeit a bit buried) in the [docs for `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

> `link_to` can also produce links with anchors or query strings:
>
> ```
> link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, anchor: "wall")
> # => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
> ```

And so:

```
<%= link_to post_path(@post, anchor: "all-comments") %>
```